# iOS App development using Phonegap with entirely WebView

Tags: cordova, hybrid

I am planning to create an iOS app which will consist of a single native navigation page.
This native navigation page will fire different (headless) URLs in the Webview. The URLs will be hosted in my server which will have its own CSS and Html. I am planning to take this approach to utilize the same transcriptional application for mobile  web users as well as native app users for different platforms as I have plans to extend the native shell for Android and Windows mobile platforms.
My question will be whether Apple App store approval process will let the app pass through since it has very little native component in it assuming I have followed other guidelines?

Please help.....

Answer (score 2):

If your PhoneGap app is just a wrapper for a remotely hosted website chances are it will be rejected during the App Store review. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an official statement from Apple about this topic and there are no "Guidelines" on this. However some people have managed to get such an App in the App Store so it's a matter of luck.

Comment: +1 to this - Phonegap apps will be approved, but in order to really make your app "pass" you will need to have a majority of your UI in the app vs loaded in. Also having conditions to check connection and let a user know that they cannot use the app without internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

in short, yes! Go for it!

As stated in PhoneGap's FAQ section:

> Apple has done a technical review, and PhoneGap apps should be ok and
>   each app will be judged on its own merits.

more info here:
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494770/FAQ
http://nachbaur.com/blog/phonegap-officially-permitted-on-the-app-store